# DropKick Plugin not wroking with Scrollability | Mobile scrolling

Tags: jquery, mobile, scroll

I am trying to get [Scrollability](http://joehewitt.github.com/scrollability/) to work with the [Dropkick plugin](http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick/). DropKick claims that it works with Scrollability, however I have NOT been able to get it to work for Mobile scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems scrollability hasn't been updated in a while, if you are using dropkick and jquery this is what I had to do, edit on your scrollability.js file the following:

Replace:

```
require.ready(function() {
   document.addEventListener(isTouch ? 'touchstart' : 'mousedown', onTouchStart, false);
   window.addEventListener('load', onLoad, false);
});
```

For this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   document.addEventListener(isTouch ? 'touchstart' : 'mousedown', onTouchStart, false);
   window.addEventListener('load', onLoad, false);
});
```

And Comment out the lines that start with 'export'.

Answer (score 1):

also check it on github scrollability.js issues

https://github.com/joehewitt/scrollability/issues/36
or
https://github.com/joehewitt/scrollability/issues/37

Comment: please, add a reference on those issues to the answer accepted here which is from where you copied the solution.